# Saving InfoPath list form as template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, list, infopath

I am trying to save a list InfoPath form as template and use it to create more lists in one of my SharePoint sites. I know how to create template using lists. My question here is Can a list which has been customized in InfoPath be made as template and used in the site. I am using SharePoint 2010 and InfoPath 2010. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As a short answer,** Yes. The customized InfoPath forms will still preserve for the newly created list.

> When creating a new list from a list template that its forms
>   customized in InfoPath, you will note that the new list forms are the
>   customized InfoPath forms, not the default SharePoint forms.